# ActionScript 3.0 mx.logging and unzip a file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, import, air, unzip

I'm developing an IOS application by using Air 3.2. I'm trying to unzip a file and searched for possible solutions.

What I found is using com.coltware.airxzip library. I downloaded and implemented these files. However some of these files are using log function and calling mx.logging.*

I'm unable to import mx.logging.* and trying to find any other solution for unzipping instead of this.

How can I import mx.logging.* or is there any other solution for unzipping?

Thanks.

Comment: mx.logging is part of Apache Flex (previously Adobe Flex) so you'll need the Flex SDK to use it - but i doubt it will work in a non-Flex application.

Comment: Flash has basic compression/decompression built-in. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d53.html for an example.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I'll try the second one.